# Can't build project with FLTK (Rust)

Tags: rust, fltk

I'm trying to build and run an example from FLTK's documentation;

```
use fltk::{app::*, button::*, frame::*, window::*};

fn main() {
    let app = App::default();
    let mut wind = Window::new(100, 100, 400, 300, "Hello, FLTK!");
    let mut frame = Frame::new(0, 0, 400, 200, "Boring label");
    let mut but = Button::new(160, 210, 80, 40, "Click me!");
    
    wind.end();
    wind.show();
    
    // Remember: Callbacks after initializing the interface
    but.set_callback(move || frame.set_label("Hello, World!"));
    
    app.run().unwrap();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Compiling fltk-sys v1.0.11
error: failed to run custom build command for `fltk-sys v1.0.11`         
    
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\mattw\Documents\engine\target\debug\build\fltk-sys-598a5e0afee061a3\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/android.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/bundled.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/link.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/main.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/source.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build/utils.rs
    
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'CMake is needed to build the fltk source files!
  Did you intend to use the fltk-bundled feature?', C:\Users\mattw\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\fltk-sys-1.0.11\build\source.rs:8:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I tried installing CMake, but it doesn't seem to help. Could you guys help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is your operating system? Did you add CMake to the PATH (and restart your terminal)? You might also use the `fltk-bundled` feature.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/blob/master/FAQ.md#build-fails-on-windows-why-cant-cmake-find-my-toolchain